# Jquery lazyload plugin won't work with external images?

Tags: jquery

Well i would like to know if this plugin 'load' the img or only fadeIn a img loaded?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [plugin's website](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) you'll see this big red box at the top

> Lazy Load is currently not usable. It
>   does not work with the latest browsers
>   as expected. I have currently no time
>   updating the code myself. Patches are
>   always welcome. If you find a solution
>   just fork and send a pull request.
>   Thanks!

Comment: Fixed now, but latest version of Lazy Load is not a drop in replacement to your webpage. New browsers load image even if you remove the src attribute with JavaScript. Now you must alter your html code. Put placeholder image into src attribute of your img tag. Real image url should be stored data-original attribute.